# listing background color not exactly the same

Tags: listings

I like SO code section colors. so I wish to use it as code listings box background color.

I use a screen capture tool to capture the code background color to png, then use GIMP tool to check the RGB value is (245,245,245). but when I use below code to define such color and use it as background color, it seems the color too dark then SO code colors.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{245,245,245}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
  captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    % comment style
  deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
  frame=single,                    % adds a frame around the code
  keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
  language=c,                 % the language of the code
  otherkeywords={*,...},           % if you want to add more keywords to the set
  numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
  numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
  showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
  showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
  showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  stepnumber=2,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
  tabsize=2,                       % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    print "hello world\n";
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output
[image]

What's wrong with my background color code?

Comment: thanks for the template for style!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `xcolor` has two variants to set up RGB colorspace, depending on whether capital letters are used or nor (`RGB` vs. `rgb`):

```
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{245,245,245}
```

which is well-known representation where min is **0** and max is **255**, and

```
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
```

which has another scale where min is **0.0** and max is **1.0**.

In your MWE you at third `\definecolor` you in fact redefined `mygray` to the darker variant, since the following lines are equal:

```
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{127,127,127}
```

If you remove this line, everything looks nice:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{245,245,245}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
%\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{ %
    backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
    captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    % comment style
    deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
    frame=single,                    % adds a frame around the code
    keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
    language=c,                 % the language of the code
    otherkeywords={*,...},           % if you want to add more keywords to the set
    numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
    numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
    showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
    showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
    showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    stepnumber=2,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
    stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
    tabsize=2,                       % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
    print "hello world\n";
    }
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also notice that `mygreen` and `mymauve` are also very dark, since they are also identical to

```
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{0,153,0}
\definecolor{mymauve}{RGB}{148,0,209}
```

but in another scale.